# Can "enclosure" be used in E-mail?

Tags: word-choice

"enclosure" has the meaning "attachment", can it be used in an e-mail?

Are they the same in this meaning?

Comment: You _could_ use it, but why _would_ you use it, when there is a more suitable word that is more understandable, and sounds more natural?

Comment: Well Bill Gates used it in a video:
https://youtu.be/FV2tMP37ygs?t=670
:D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think I'd understand *enclosure* if you meant *an email attachment*.  I think *enclosed* might work, though:

> Please take a look at the *enclosed file*.

I think I might understand this.  **But!**  This is a metaphor for including something in the envelope of a physical letter, and as time goes on I think it may be understood by fewer and fewer people.  I don't think it's **terribly** clear, so I wouldn't recommend saying it.  I'd recommend using the word *attachment* (or *attached*) instead:

> Please take a look at the *attached file*.

or:

> I've included a couple *attachments* in this email.  Could you please take a look at them and get back to me?

There's no real reason to use any other word.  You can say *attachment* over and over without worrying about using synonyms to keep it interesting.

Comment: Yep! +1. There's also the common wording "Please find attached [the type of/name of file that's attached]." :)

Answer (score 0):

*Enclosure* means "something that is placed in an envelope with a letter." For emails, you would use *attachment* or *attached file* as snailboat suggested.